# Issues in integration of Language integration in android for dynamic text

Tags: android, internationalization, google-translate, machine-translation

I want to integrate multiple languages in my application for my dynamic string value. This string value is not in my resource folder so I tried below APIs for integrate purpose:

1. Google Translate API
2. Yandex API
3. Microsoft Translate API

And also try below code:

When I integrate above API it will not work properly. They give limit access of character error and I also purchase in $1 Google API than it is also give same error.

In Yandex API it remove some text content due to limit access character.

Apart form this I also try below code:

```
   String test="My name is john tokest";
    try {
    String translatedText = Translate.execute(test, Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH);//You can pass params as per text input and desired output.
    System.out.println(translatedText)
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Still I'm not getting proper result which I want so any idea if it is possible translate string form one language to other?

Comment: I think more preferable option for multiple translation is provide local resource.

Comment: Haresh Chhelana :  but it is possible only for fix text value not for dynamic text

Comment: Haresh Chhelana : i want to change my text value run time from one language to other language as i mention in my question